# add param to FB.login() callback function if no session is returned by FB.getLoginStatus()

Tags: parameters, authentication, facebook, callback

i'm having trouble building a function fbPostToWall(picUrl) that uses FB.getLoginStatus() to post a received picture url to a users wall. This part works fine as there is a session response:

```
function fbPostToWall(picUrl) {

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

        if (response.session) {

            // logged in and connected user, someone you know
            FB.ui(
                {
                    method: 'feed',
                    picture: picUrl,
                    ...
                },
                function(response) {
                    if (response && response.post_id) {
                        alert("Post was successful");
                    } else {
                        alert("Post was not successful");
                    }
                }
            );

        } else {

            // no user session available, someone you dont know
            FB.login(myCallbackFn);
        }
    });

}
```

But if there is no session response, i try to call FB.login(myCallbackFn) with my own callback function "myCallbackFn" which looks like this:

```
function myCallbackFn(response) {
    // if we dont have a session, just hide the user info
    if (!response.session) {
        return;
    }

    if(response.session) {

        //get picture previously saved in Session
        $.post("picture.php", { getPicture: "" },

            function(data){

                // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                FB.ui(
                    {
                        method: 'feed',
                        ...
                    },
                    function(response) {
                        if (response && response.post_id) {
                            alert("Post was successful");
                        } else {
                            alert("Post was not successful");
                        }
                    }
                );

            }
        );              

    }
}
```

When the callback part gets called, the fb popup window doesn't open, instead the browsers popup warning appears. When i grant the permission to open the popup, i can login with fb and post the picture to my wall. But now a new popup window opens (Title "XD Proxy") which stays opened after the post was submitted. What is this and how can i avoid that? Can i simplify both functions by adding the picture url to the callback function as a param? Thanks!